# CGRectIntersectsRect Problem

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cgrect

I am making a app with a maze, I put a ball inside the maze in the interface builder (I put an outlet for it) I have a touchesMoved:

```
 -(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
CGPoint point;
point = [touch locationInView:self.view];

ball.center = point;

if (CGRectIntersectsRect(ball.frame, maze.frame)) {
   //my stuff
}


   }
```

I have two CGRectIntersectsRect if statements, I say, if the ball's frame touches the maze's frame, then // my stuff happens, but for some reason, whenever i try to move the ball, without touching the frame of the maze, // my stuff happens. I dont know why, maybe it is because the ball is IN the maze, probably not because i said if cgrectintersectsrect frame not bounds. so why is this happening?

I have another iboutlet of a uiimageview called flag, i have the same cgrectintersectsrect type of code, and it works in the same touchesMoved, so why does this not work

Comment: What is `maze`? Are you sure it's not `nil`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [CGRectIntersectsRect](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6698085/cgrectintersectsrect)

Answer (score 1):

try this one

```
UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];

CGPoint point;

point = [touch locationInView:self.view];


point = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL: point];


if (CGRectIntersectsRect(ball.bounds, maze.bounds)) {


//frame - x,y,w,h

//bounds- w,h
```

Comment: im getting errors saying: use of undeclared identifier //all of the letters and frame and bounds, what is x,y,w,h and w,h?

Comment: what do you mean? So are you saying that I should change frame to bounds?

Comment: ya mean cidirector not ccdirector right, if i do ccdirector, i get an error cause it doesnt what wat that is, BUT if i change it to cidirector, then i get 3 errors saying: no know class method for selector sharedDirector, assigning to cgpoint from incompatible type id, no known instance method for selector convertToGL