# CGRectIntersectsRect

Tags: objective-c, xcode

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [CGRectIntersectsRect Problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6696393/cgrectintersectsrect-problem)

I am making a app with a maze, I put a ball inside the maze in the interface builder (I put an outlet for it) I have a touchesMoved:

```
-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
    CGPoint point;
    point = [touch locationInView:self.view];

    ball.center = point;

    if (CGRectIntersectsRect(ball.frame, maze.frame)) {
       //my stuff
    }
}
```

I have two CGRectIntersectsRect if statements, I say, if the ball's frame touches the maze's frame, then // my stuff happens, but for some reason, whenever i try to move the ball, without touching the frame of the maze, // my stuff happens. I dont know why, maybe it is because the ball is IN the maze, probably not because i said if cgrectintersectsrect frame not bounds. so why is this happening?

Comment: possible dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6696393/cgrectintersectsrect-problem

Comment: Please don't double-post questions. You can keep your question fresh by editing it to be clearer if you're not getting answers. The site will also bubble up unanswered questions for people to see.

Answer (score 8):

`CGRectIntersectsRect` is going to return true if any part of rect1 lies inside of rect2.  So while your ball is completely inside your maze, your intersection test will always be true.

Comment: oh ok then, i didnt realize that, how can i fix that then

Comment: not sure exactly what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: im trying to make it so when im inside the maze i // my stuff doesnt happen, because right now as you said, since i start with it inside, the cgrectintersectsrect will return as yes

Comment: where is the maze? is it the entire view? where are the walls? to see if the frame of ball is completely inside the frame of the maze, use `CGRectContainsRect(maze.frame, ball.frame)`

Comment: yeh it still doesnt work

Comment: presumably with walls drawn in the image.  you'll have a difficult time detecting collisions with walls drawn that way.

Comment: difficult doesnt mean impossible

Answer (score -1):

If you want to detect when the rect of your ball is touching the edge of the rect of your maze (rather than just anywhere in the maze), you need to test for `!CGRectEqualToRect(CGRectIntersection(ball, maze), maze)` in addition to `CGRectIntersectsRect(ball, maze)`.

Comment: this code just leads to tons of errors

Comment: Can you please elaborate @user842059? What errors are you seeing?