# ios collison detection in CALayer

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I'm using 3 CALayers which are animating Up and Down in a line, how can i detect collision between these layers, i have used CGRectIntersectsRect to detect collision but i didn't get anything. Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CGRectIntersectRect` is a function which returns the boolean value, if one object intersects with other object. You must passed the two parameters(rect of two objects whose intersection you want to check) for this function.
Please send some lines of code for better understanding.

[possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6698085/cgrectintersectsrect)

[possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6696393/cgrectintersectsrect-problem)

Comment: i have done like this,
if (CGRectIntersectsRect([[mylayer1 presentationLayer]frame], [[mylayer2 presentationLayer]frame]))
    {
        NSLog(@"intersected");
    }
I have put this code in animationDidStop function..

Comment: Try to get the frames before CGRectIntersectsRect function call then passed that frames to this function. Also print both the frames & let me know your feedback.

Comment: I had edited my answer please look on the given URL & if it sorts your problem then upvote & accept the answer.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21062/discussion-between-girish-and-harish-saran)